# grouping input files with incremental names to divide a computation into smaller ones

Tags: linux, bash, loops, grouping, data-wrangling

I created a script to run a function that takes a specific file and compares it to several others. The files that I have to scan for the matches are more than 900 and incrementally named like this:

A001-abc.txt A001-efg.txt [..] A002-efg.txt A002-hjk.txt [..] A120-xwz.txt (no whitespaces)

The script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in *.txt; do
    bedtools function /mydir/myfile.txt *.txt> output.txt
done
```

Now, the computation is extremely intensive and can't be completed. How can I group the files according to their incremental name and perform the computation on files A001-abc A001-def then go to A002-abc, A002-def.., to A123-xyz and so on?

I was thinking that by finding a way to specify the name with an incremental variable and then grouping them, I could divide the computation in many smaller ones. Is it reasonable and doable?

Many thanks!

Comment: What's the point in doing `for f in *.txt` and using `$f` nowhere?

Comment: What's the point in overwriting `output.txt` in each loop cycle?

Comment: You're accidentally running the command [file count] times on *every file.*

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that you're not using `$f`.  Try using this line in the for-loop instead.  Also, use `>>` so the output appends instead of overwriting the output file.

```
bedtools function /mydir/myfile.txt "$f" >> output.txt
```

But if you still want to break it up, you might try a double loop like this:

```
for n in $(seq --format="%03.f" 1 120); do
    for f in "A$n"*; do
        bedtools function /mydir/myfile.txt "$f" >> "${n}output.txt"
    done
done
```

The values of `$n` from the output of the `seq` command is `001 002 .. 120`.

So the inner loop loops through `A001*` `A002*` .. `A120*`.